# Odata Client Code Generator not generating code after VS Update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, odata, odata-v4

Client code is not generated after updating Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.
Tried to generate client code using following extension.

1. Odata V4 Client Code Generator
2. Odata Connected Service Extension

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a bug in Visual Studio update.
Issue has been reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/527) and in visual [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2451005).